# Find json key where another key is condition within same object in Ansible

Tags: json, parsing, ansible, vmware

How to list key value as another key in same object as condition
- I want to list all "**guest_name**"'s into new list where "**power_state**" is "**poweredOn**"

I'm using vmware_vm_info module and parsing data with **json_query**

Output:

```
    {
        "guest_name": "Ubuntu sec 10.9",
        "ip_address": "",
        "power_state": "poweredOff",
    },

    {
        "guest_fullname": "Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)",
        "guest_name": "Ubuntu 10.8",
        "power_state": "poweredOn",
    },...]
```

Wanted result:

"guest_name": "name", "name2",...

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectattr` to filter all `poweredOn` instances, then use `map` filter to extract `guest_name` from each instance.

Given that the json resides in `my_var`, you can do it as following:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_var | selectattr('power_state', 'match', 'poweredOn') | map(attribute='guest_name') | list }}"
```

This will output the list of instances that are "poweredOn":

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Ubuntu 10.8"
    ]
}
```